# How to convert shell to perl

Tags: perl, shell

This is part of Shell script.
This is to check disk Usage.
I want to know how this could convert to perl script ?
Please help me for this.

```
DFCMD="df -P"

for fs in `eval $DFCMD`; do

FS=`echo $fs | awk ' { print $1 } '`

done
```

Thanks

Comment: It is wrong to expect free solutions from Stack Overflow. If you don't know Perl at all then this is the wrong place to start learning. You should spend a few weeks reading books and trying exercises until you are confident that you understand Perl and how you can use it. After that, if you have written your own solution but still have a problem getting it to work, you should come back here and show your program and describe the problem you have. Then we will help you.

Comment: It is not possible to convert this shell script to perl, because its purpose is to set a shell variable; perl can set an environment variable and spawn a new shell, but cannot set a variable in the shell that called it.  (There are ways to get around that, but that would be a perl program that did something different.)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a 1liner to do it, but I'd do this (un tested)

```
my @command = qw/df -P/;
open(my $in, "-|", @command) or die "Can't run `@command`: $!";
while(<$in>) {
    my ($first_col) = split;
    print "$first_col\n";
}
```

Comment: (1) In scalar context, `split` returns the field count, the fields in list context. We could either assign to an `@array` (`my @cols = split; print "$cols[0]\n"`). Or, we can unpack the first element from the list, as shown per my edit. (2) `split /\s+\, $_` is not likely to work. Being the default variable, `$_` doesn't have to be specified. The regex `/\s+/` is similar to the default behavior, so we'll use that. (3) `open` should produce lexical filehandles. Passing it a list of arguments is safer, as this circumvents the shell. Also, error handling is good.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -le 'print /(\S+)/ for `df -P`'
```

Comment: `df -P | perl -anE'say $F[0]' # even shorter` ;-)

Comment: @amon yes, but it's kinda more shell solution and OP wanted more perl :) btw, no chomping and `say` produce one more newline.

Answer (score 0):

well, in perl, it is often use the system() function to execute the shell command, but the system() function can not return the output of the command.You can use backticks (``) to get the output. Use the out put, you can convert the shell script to perl script

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl
  2 use strict;
  3 use warnings;
  4
  5 my @output = split('\r\n', `df -P | awk '{print \$1}'`);
  6 print @output;
```

Comment: Thanks for all. I've tested all your suggestion and it still not worked as I expected.

The reason I asked this is to use each variable for some operation.

Suppose, If I get FS variable for each mount point, 
I can check if the mounted directory is greater than 90%.

So I need to read each line using perl script.

Yes, I'm sorry that I'm not expert of Perl. lol